# Force url when using Get method on form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a simple form inside my Index View like this:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get)) {%>

<%= Html.TextBox("query") %>

<% } %>
```

What this does is when a user submits the form it appends a query on the url like `domain.com/?query=henry`

However my Index method also adds additional things like `domain.com/Page/2` so therefore if someone has viewed page 2 and then submits the form it will do this `domain.com/Page/2?query=henry` which is not what I want.

How can I force the form to just do this: 'domain.com/?query=henry` so essentially going to default Index? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to clear those routeValues when declaring your form

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new { page = "" }, FormMethod.Get)) {%>
```

otherwise it will use the values that it finds on the current view

Comment: you and I are high-fiving super-big-time